# Linear, homogeneous, partial differential equations: why does separation of variables work?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Typically, when solving a linear, homogeneous PDE (among other types), at least in two variables, we assume that the solution is of the form:

$$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$$

And then proceed to re-arrange and solve what become two ODEs.  However, I've always been curious: how do we know that solutions not of that form do not exist?  In other words, why is it that once we solve the PDE after separating the variables, we all agree that we have found "the solution"?  Could there be other possible functions that satisfy the PDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of separation of variables works in case of linear PDE and leads to an infinity of particular solutions on the form :
$$u_\lambda(x,y)=X_\lambda(x)Y_\lambda(y)$$
The indice $\lambda$ is there in order to remind that, in the function $X(x)$ and $Y(y)$ , there is an arbitrary constant $\lambda$. This constant appears because those functions are the solutions of ODEs.

Any linear combination of $u_\lambda(x,y)$ with different $\lambda$ is also solution of the PDE : that is why the PDE must be linear.
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{\text{any }\lambda}a_\lambda u_\lambda(x,y)$$
where $a_\lambda$ are any constants.

A more general solution is obtained thanks to integral instead of discret sum :
$$u(x,y)=\int A(\lambda) u(\lambda,x,y)d\lambda$$
where $A(\lambda)$ is any function (insofar the integration be possible). Note that general function can be a sum of functions.

The solution can be unique if some boundary conditions are well defined.

Given the boundary conditions, one have to determine a finite or infinite number of coefficients $a_\lambda$ (in the discrete form) or to determine the function $A(\lambda)$ (in the integral form). In fact, this is generally the most difficult part of the task, much more difficult than finding the particular solutions.

Note: each particular solution of the PDE doesn't fit the boundary conditions. This is the convenient sum (discrete or integral) of particular solutions which fits the boundary conditions.